# Logging in to a website cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL for the first time. I need to login to a site.
I have problem with setting cookie file and to retrive, so that i can acces that page not just one time, but several times.
I found the code on the web, for logging in to a site and Scrap a page for some detailed info, cause to get that page it takes to much time.
so i just want to know if it is OK! the code belove(it is just for login in the code for Scraping its not ready)

```
<?php

curl_login('http://mywantedsite.com/login.php','user=******&pass=******','','off');

echo curl_grab_page('http://mywantedsite.com/somepage.php','','off');

function curl_login($url,$data,$proxy,$proxystatus){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    if ($proxystatus == 'on') {
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    }
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();      // prevent any output
    return curl_exec ($login); // execute the curl command
    ob_end_clean();  // stop preventing output
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);    
}                  

function curl_grab_page($site,$proxy,$proxystatus){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    if ($proxystatus == 'on') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();      // prevent any output
    return curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command
    ob_end_clean();  // stop preventing output
    curl_close ($ch);
}  
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to check if you are posting all the "posting fields"..
some sites use security tokens or sessions ids to prevent bots from logging on their sites.
anyway, you need to install Live HTTP headers firefox extension. open it and try to login manually, then see whats being posted actually when you press login button. 
after you get the values. add then to the first function and test again.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly use `$strPostFields` to store login name and password, then use

```
$this->m_strResourceCurl = curl_init();
```

and in your cURL script add this

```
curl_setopt( $this->m_strResourceCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strPostFields );
```

I hope you get this little code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you add the URL parameter at

```
$login = curl_init($url);
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_URL` is just fine. But don't use ob, rather let curl return the output itself and catch it with `$output = curl_exec($login);`